# How to auto set a form value on the next page using link_to? (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and am looking to do something very simple but don't know the correct syntax. I have 2 buttons one for creating a new page and one for creating a new post. Both a page and a post save in the same database table and are controlled through a boolean field called 'static'. A page therefore has a static value of 1 and a post 0. What I want to do is simply auto set this value in a form (and hide it) when I click new page or post. I imagined the link to create a new page would work something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'New Page', new_page_path(:static => "1") %>
```

This doesn't work so I tried to create a new_static page action and a new_post page action with correcting routing (for displaying only pages I created a show_static action used the following link_to and it works fine):

```
<%= link_to "Pages", show_static_pages_path(@pages), :method => :get %>
```

The problem is when I created the new_static page action it expects an id for some reason.

```
new_static_page GET    /pages/:id/new_static(.:format)   pages#new_static
```

I would prefer to not mess around with new actions and routing and simply set the value with link_to. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to work uphill against RESTful routes and the Rails way here. I recommend separating your Page MVC from your Post MVC, and all will become easier.

Comment: By separating both do you mean also creating a new table for posts or is there a way to CRUD on 1 table from 2 models? Sorry if this seems elementary.

Comment: You'll want two separate tables and models at least, (one model per table) and likely two separate controllers and views. And this is both elementary for Rails, but intermediate/advanced for folks coming into Rails. Maybe take some time to watch the pros explain good RESTful practices. This link has good explanations and links to other good resources: http://everydayrails.com/2010/07/18/understanding-rest-and-routes.html